# Como inserir imagem na planilha xsl com php? Sendo que no banco de dados esta salvo somente o caminho da imagem em uma pasta no servidor?

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, imagem, inserir

O que esta sendo passado para a planilha é somente o caminho da imagem, mas estou precisando que imagem seja passado para a planilha.

A imagem que esta na pasta do servidor, sendo que somente é gravado no servidor o caminho da imagem.

```
<?php

    header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
    header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=relatorio.xls" );

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_manifestacoes";
            $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo 'id' . "\t" . 'Row Key' . "\t" . 'Time Stamp' . "\t" . 'Comentários' . "\t" . 'Concessionaria' . "\t" . 'Cpf' . "\t" . 'Data Manifestção' . "\t" . 'Email' . "\t" . 'Imvd' . "\t" . 'Latitude' . "\t" . 'Longitude' . "\t" . 'Nome' . "\t" . 'Reverso' . "\t" . 'Rodovia' . "\t" . 'Status' . "\t" . 'Telefone' . "\t" . 'Tipo de Manifestação' . "\t" . 'Data do Atendimento' . "\t" . 'Cidade' . "\t" . 'AproximadoKm' . "\t" . 'Sentido' . "\t" . "\n";
                    echo $row['id'] . "\t" . $row['rowKey'] . "\t" . $row['timestamp'] . "\t" . $row['comentarios'] . "\t" . $row['concessionaria'] . "\t" . $row['cpf'] . "\t" . $row['datamanif'] . "\t" . $row['email'] . "\t" . $row['imvd'] . "\t" . $row['latitude'] . "\t" . $row['longitude'] . "\t" . $row['nome'] . "\t" . $row['reverso'] . "\t" . $row['rodovia'] . "\t" . $row['status'] . "\t" . $row['telefone'] . "\t" . $row['tipoManifestacao'] . "\t" . $row['dataAtendimento'] . "\t" . $row['cidade'] . "\t" . $row['kmAproximado'] . "\t" . $row['sentido'] . "\t" . $row['imgResposta'] . "\t" . "\n";
                }

?>


header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=relatorio.xls" );

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_manifestacoes";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo 'id' . "\t" . 'Row Key' . "\t" . 'Time Stamp' . "\t" . 'Comentários' . "\t" . 'Concessionaria' . "\t" . 'Cpf' . "\t" . 'Data Manifestção' . "\t" . 'Email' . "\t" . 'Imvd' . "\t" . 'Latitude' . "\t" . 'Longitude' . "\t" . 'Nome' . "\t" . 'Reverso' . "\t" . 'Rodovia' . "\t" . 'Status' . "\t" . 'Telefone' . "\t" . 'Tipo de Manifestação' . "\t" . 'Data do Atendimento' . "\t" . 'Cidade' . "\t" . 'AproximadoKm' . "\t" . 'Sentido' . "\t" . "\n";
                echo $row['id'] . "\t" . $row['rowKey'] . "\t" . $row['timestamp'] . "\t" . $row['comentarios'] . "\t" . $row['concessionaria'] . "\t" . $row['cpf'] . "\t" . $row['datamanif'] . "\t" . $row['email'] . "\t" . $row['imvd'] . "\t" . $row['latitude'] . "\t" . $row['longitude'] . "\t" . $row['nome'] . "\t" . $row['reverso'] . "\t" . $row['rodovia'] . "\t" . $row['status'] . "\t" . $row['telefone'] . "\t" . $row['tipoManifestacao'] . "\t" . $row['dataAtendimento'] . "\t" . $row['cidade'] . "\t" . $row['kmAproximado'] . "\t" . $row['sentido'] . "\t" . $row['imgResposta'] . "\t" . "\n";
            }
```

Comment: Acho mais fácil utilizar a classe [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). Ela vêm com alguns exemplos, inclusive o que você precisa.